# Dependency Injector not working on DDD project

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to do dependency injection in my .NET project (application layer). I have two Base files for the interfaces and the classes. So I put this in my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppAnexo), typeof(AppAnexo));
```

but Im getting 2 errors

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SisPenalidades.Application.Interfaces.IAppAnexo Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: SisPenalidades.Application.Services.AppAnexo': Unable to resolve service for type 'SisPenalidades.Application.Interfaces.Base.IApp`1[SisPenalidades.Domain.Entities.Anexo]' while attempting to activate 'SisPenalidades.Application.Services.AppAnexo'.

and

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SisPenalidades.Application.Interfaces.Base.IApp`1[SisPenalidades.Domain.Entities.Anexo]' while attempting to activate 'SisPenalidades.Application.Services.AppAnexo'.

What am I doing wrong? I did the same thing on my repository layer and it works, but it doesnt works on the Application layer.

the project structure:

[image]

Obs. if i remove the App.cs base class and put their methods direclty on the AppAnexo.cs class, it works

Relevant classes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thing, I am not sure if it is necessary for using `typeof(IAppAnexo)` and `typeof(AppAnexo)`. Just use `IAppAnexo` and `AppAnexo`. It will resolve the type without additional reflection. But to solve the problem, what does the actual class look like? It must obviously inherit `IAppAnexo` in order to properly resolve the type.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your `AppAnexo` class has a Constructor dependency on `IApp<T>`, and you've forgotten to include a Dependency Injection mapping from `IApp<T>` to `App<T>`

Try adding the following in your Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApp<Anexo>, App<Anexo>>();
```

I find it clearer to use the generics syntax for the DI, as above, but you can use the `typeof` if you prefer.

Edit: *many thanks to @Stephen spotting the original question hints at generics. So if you need `IApp<T>` for any given `T` then try this:*

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IApp<>), typeof(App<>));
```

Edit 2: based on your extra info on the class definitions, maybe this is what you're wanting. My assumptions for this are:

- `App` is like your repository or DB layer, because you called it dbcontext
- `AppAnexo` is your main application logic

If that's true, then you want something like this:

```cs
public class App<T> : IApp<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context; // ...or whatever your DB access is done via.

    public App(DbContent context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // etc.
```

```cs
public interface IAppAnexo // NOTE, DO NOT INHERIT IApp
{
    // etc.
```

```cs
public class AppAnexo : IAppAnexo // NOTE, DO NOT INHERIT App
{
    private readonly IApp<SomeType> _repo1;
    private readonly IApp<AnotherType> _repo2;

    public AppAnexo(IApp<SomeType> repository1, IApp<AnotherType> repository2)
    {
        _repo1 = repository1;
        _repo2 = repository2;
    }

    // etc.
```

Comment: I add the line builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IApp<>), typeof(App<>)); but now i got this error: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'SisPenalidades.Application.Interfaces.Base.IApp<SisPenalidades.Domain.Entities.Anexo>'.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines (i.e. the class name and Constructor dependencies) of your relevant classes, so we can help further? Basically it sound like you have some classes that have a dependency on each other, which isn't going to work.

Comment: I've added the relevant classes on the question

Comment: You've got `AppAnexo` inheriting `App`, and also taking `App` (via IApp) as a Constructor dependency. Rather, `AppAnexo` should _either_ inherit `App`, _or_ take a Constructor dependency. This suggests you've got your class inheritance/dependency strategy mixed up somewhere.

Comment: I suspect what you want to do is remove the inheritance and instead use DI (i.e. "composition") to achieve it. I'll modify my answer now, to suggest what you should do.